Fail2ban filter for "//xmlrpc.php" doesn't trigger bans
We're getting regular waves of Apache requests (Ubuntu 24.04) like this:
www.server.com:80 104.197.225.110 - - [27/Sep/2024:22:13:06 +0000] "POST //xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 200 818 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

And have a fail2ban ruleset for this:
[INCLUDES]

before = apache-common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST).*(/wp-login.php|/xmlrpc.php).*$
ignoreregex =

with jail.local:
[wordpress]
enabled = true
banaction = iptables-allports
port = all
logpath = /var/log/apache2/access.log
datepattern = %%d/%%b/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S %%z
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
bantime = 3600
backend = auto

However, if I run:
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/access.log wordpress.conf
I get:
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : wordpress, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : {^LN-BEG} : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

I note that requests for "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 404 do get matches though.
I've tried various permutations of the regexp but had no luck in banning offending IPs (resorted to adding to iptables using a shell script but it's causing problems with some hosts). What would be the correct filter to apply for this?

After using this checker to help me debug the regexp, I found the following to work for requests for both /xml-rpc.php and //xml-rpc.php.
Note that I added the datepattern macros to the filter as well, as fail2ban-regexp was showing no matches on that before. Also extended it to cover false positives with Jetpack, and wp-login.php attempts:
[INCLUDES]

before = apache-common.conf

[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST>.*] "POST (|.*)\/xmlrpc\.php.*
            ^<HOST>.*] "GET (|.*)\/xmlrpc\.php.*
            ^<HOST> .* "POST .*wp-login.php
ignoreregex = ^<HOST>.*] "POST (|.*)\/xmlrpc\.php\?for=jetpack.*

datepattern = ^[^\[]*\[({DATE})
              {^LN-BEG}

The entry in jail.local is as follows:
[wordpress]
enabled = true
action = iptables-multiport[name=wordpress, port="http,https"]
logpath = /var/log/apache2/access.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
bantime = 3600

(As an aside, I couldn't get fail2ban's regexps to work with logical OR statements like (GET|POST) - apparently only matching the first one?)
